# Ethernet hub - is it an active device?

Tags: ethernet, hub

When building a small home ethernet network, we normally use **switch** to connect all cables together. I remember 10 years ago it was also possible to buy a much cheaper device called **hub** which can be used instead of a switch on 10 mbit/s UTP based network. When I read hub article in Wikipedia, they say it is an *active device*. My question is: Why is a hub an active device, or is each hub really active? Hubs I used were simple devices without power supply and they simply connected all cables together (with a few diodes or something logically equivalent). So in my eyes it is a passive device, or I don't clearly understand the meaning of active/passive here.

Answer (score 2):

Ethernet hubs can be passive, however they are limited in connectivity range by the signal loss through cabling and the hub.  There are [designs](http://www.eeweb.com/blog/circuit_projects/building-a-passive-ethernet-hub) available to build them yourself.  I don't know of any current manufacturers that make them since switches have made hubs obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Hubs were always active as they contain powered electronics.  I've never seen one that was completely passive requiring no extra power source to make it function.

The difference between a basic switch and a hub is that a hub broadcasts the packets to all other links.  A switch is smarter and only sends packets to links that require it.  So switches will always need to be powered to run their logic chips.

But why do hubs need to be active? One of those reasons that comes to mind is to ensure that they meet the performance requirements of the 10baseT standard which is 100m.  If it was entirely passive like 10base2 you run into distance limitations as the the wire resistance and capacitance increases with length and loading.  You can't meet these requirements with a purely passive design.  Therefore each Ethernet link would need it's own active driver.

There used to be old style ethernet which was [10base2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/10BASE2) which acted passively.
[image: 10base2].

The disadvantage of this being that if you break the cable you break the connection for potentially all computers.  It was as I recall somewhat unreliable compared to what we have now.

That being said, 10Base2 had a 200m length limit and up to 30 nodes.  But look at the wires, they are very much thicker then 10BaseT. Also you can't buy 10Base2 anymore and it was limited to 10mbit.

Modern copper ethernet uses [10baseT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair) (t for twisted pair) for it's cabling and is much more reliable.

Comment: Please make emphasis on active and passive characteristics and what makes a device passive or active.